# Using JQuery to show/ hide buttons only in this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

As an exercise I'm trying to use jQuery to see more/ see less content in a series of divs. I've created buttons to trigger the see more and see less events, and simultaneously I'm hiding the "see more" button when the div is expanded, or the "see less" button when the div is shrunk.

My problem is that when a user clicks on a button, it changes all buttons on the page, instead of the button within that specific div.

I've tried solving this issue a few different ways with no success. I sort of understand how to use $(this) and how to traverse element... but I'm not able to solve this problem.

Here is the jQuery that I'm working with->

```
//hide "see less" button
$(".less-button").hide();
//capture click on more button
//add class to enlarge div
$(".more-button").click(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().addClass("more");
  //hide "see more" button
  $(".more-button").hide();
  //show "see less" button
  $(".less-button").show();
});
//capture click on less button
//remove class to shrink div
$(".less-button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass("more");
  //hide "see less" button again
  $(".less-button").hide();
  //show "see more" button... again
  $(".more-button").show();
});
```

Here is a link to my codepen for the page->
http://codepen.io/seanpierce/pen/vNeVJm/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See it working here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpMwMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your even handlers, look for the sibling button:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BowGJg

```
//hide "see less" button
$(".less-button").hide();
//capture click on more button
//add class to enlarge div
$(".more-button").click(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().addClass("more");
  //hide "see more" button
  $(this).hide();
  //show "see less" button
  $(this).siblings(".less-button").show();
});
//capture click on less button
//remove class to shrink div
$(".less-button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().removeClass("more");
  //hide "see less" button again
  $(this).hide();
  //show "see more" button... again
  $(this).siblings(".more-button").show();
});
```

Comment: I just used his initial javascript as a base. I'm not here to confuse. I'm here to solve the issue the OP has using his code so that he can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only find the button of the parent that you clicked on.

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3v0sr2y/

```
//hide "see less" button
$(".less-button").hide();
//capture click on more button
//add class to enlarge div
$(".more-button").click(function(){ 
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  parent.addClass("more");
  //hide "see more" button
  parent.find(".more-button").hide();
  //show "see less" button
  parent.find(".less-button").show();
});
//capture click on less button
//remove class to shrink div
$(".less-button").click(function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  parent.removeClass("more");
  //hide "see less" button again
  parent.find(".less-button").hide();
  //show "see more" button... again
  parent.find(".more-button").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$(".more-button").click(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().addClass("more");
  //hide "see more" button
  $(this).hide();
  //show "see less" button
  $(this).parent().find(".less-button").show();
 });
 //capture click on less button
  //remove class to shrink div
 $(".less-button").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().removeClass("more");
    //hide "see less" button again
    $(this).hide();
    //show "see more" button... again
    $(this).parent().find(".more-button").show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're toggling classes on the container just use CSS to show/hide appropriate buttons:

JS:

```
// you don't need separate listeners
$(".more-button, .less-button").click(function(){ 
  // toggleClass will remove a class name if present or add if not. 
  // it can take multiple class names.
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("less more");
});
```

CSS:

```
/* hide .more-button inside .post element with class .more, 
   and .less-button inside .post element with class .less
 */
.post.more .more-button, .post.less .less-button {
  display:none;
}
```

demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWLqLe